# How to search by POST method in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to display a search result page. If the query is found, it will be redirected to the entry page. Else if a substring of the query is found, a search result page will be displayed with the entry shown as a link and if click that link, the entry page will display. Here is my code as below, please help:

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("edit", views.edit, name="edit"),
    path("<str:title>", views.entry, name="entry")
]
```

views.py:

```
from . import util
import markdown2
import random
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django import forms

def index(request):
    entries = util.list_entries()
    rand = random.choice(entries)
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "random": rand,
        "entries": entries
    })

def entry(request, title):
    entries = util.list_entries()
    rand = random.choice(entries)
    try: 
        mark_content = util.get_entry(title)
        output = markdown2.markdown(mark_content)
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/title.html", {
            "content": output,
            "random": rand,
            "title": title
        })

    except TypeError:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html", {
            "random": rand
        })

def search(request):
    # get search input from user
    search_entry = request.POST['q']
    # results = list()

    # get entries list
    entries = util.list_entries()

    # search list
    results = []
    
    # try to search if there is such entry in entries
    if request.method == "POST":
        if search_entry in entries:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("title", args=(search_entry,)))
        
        else: 
            for entry in entries: 
                if search_entry in entry: 
                    results.append(entry)
                    return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", {
                        "results": results
                    })
```

layout.html:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'encyclopedia/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="sidebar col-lg-2 col-md-3">
                <h2>Wiki</h2>
                <form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
                </form>
                <div>
                    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="">Create New Page</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="{% url 'entry' random %}">Random Page</a>
                </div>
                {% block nav %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
            <div class="main col-lg-10 col-md-9">
                {% block body %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

search.html

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}

    Search Results
    
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    <h2>Search results:</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for result in results %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'entry' result %}">{{ result }}</a>
            </li>
        {% empty %}
            <li>No result.</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>  

{% endblock %}
```

Q1: I am using POST as the query method, because I want to display the URL as /wiki/search for search result page, but with GET as the method, the URL will be like ?q=&. I am a bit confused about this part, because when I search HTML in wikipedia, the URL will be like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML, but when I right click and inspect the page, the method is "GET".

Q2: Should I use TypeError here? If the user type the URL as wiki/hello, and there is not an entry page as hello, then the error page will display, indicating that there is no hello page.

Q3: When I searched, it always shows error page. Why? I have given args to the entry function, but it seems it doesn't get the right argument.

Comment: I think I know the answer about question 2. It should be a TypeError, because in another python file, there is a function returns None if user types something in URL not in entries. I was right. Please ignore this question and help with the other two. Thanks.

Comment: I think there should be some improvement in the way of achieving random link. Haven't figured out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django import forms


from . import util
import markdown2

class NewEntryForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)


class EditForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100, initial='title')
    Edit_Content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, initial='content')



def index(request):
    if util.get_entry(request.GET.get("q")) is not None:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/wiki/" + request.GET.get("q"))
    
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries()
    })
    

def mdpage(request, title):
    if util.get_entry(request.GET.get("q")) is not None:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/wiki/" + request.GET.get("q"))
    conversion = markdown2.markdown(util.get_entry(title))
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/mdpage.html", {
        "mdconvert" : conversion
    })

def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        NewEntry = NewEntryForm(request.POST)
        if NewEntry.is_valid():
                title = NewEntry.cleaned_data['title']
                content = NewEntry.cleaned_data['content']
                if (title in util.list_entries()):
                    return HttpResponse ("Error Entry already exists")
                else:    
                    util.save_entry(title, content)
                    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
                    "entries": util.list_entries()
                    })
        else:
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/createpage.html", {
             "NewEntry": NewEntry
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/createpage.html", {
            "NewEntry": NewEntryForm()
        })
```

Comment: you dont need to create a search box page since you already created the page with the markdown convertion you just need to redirect the page with an if condition,

Comment: i am taking this course now and i'm stuck on the editing page and random page

Comment: Your search works! Thanks a lot! Could you please share the link about where did you find the way you wrote this part: `return HttpResponseRedirect("/wiki/" + request.GET.get("q"))`. Also, I think maybe giving it a separate function is a better idea, because we are also required to search for substrings and display a list of substring search result page and click the link to display the entry page. I finished random page. I am happy if you takes it for your reference, a better way of writing the code could've been achieved though I think.

Comment: for random if we use random.choice() it will always send us to that same page unless i rerun the program.
is there any possible way that each time we click on random page it takes us to a different page??

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. What I understand about random is, we need to give the function a variable, which is generated by random.choice(), and give this variable to our view to display the content page of the title.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer to Q3: the order by which urls in urls.py are created.

Django will look for a path from top to bottom, so it stops at entry function as the second and didn't get to the search path below. I changed the order and it doesn't show error page when I search anymore. Though the search still doesn't work. Need help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the search function with the help from Ralph Borgi, now both word and substring search work.

It should be GET method, the only problem got me stuck is, I didn't know how to make url looking like "/wiki/CSS" for example, without the pattern of ?q=. The code is as below for anyone interested:

```
def search(request):
    # get search input from user
    search_entry = request.GET['q']
    # results = list()

    # get entries list
    entries = util.list_entries()
    rand = random.choice(entries)
    # search list
    results = []
    
    # try to search if there is such entry in entries
    if request.method == "GET":
        if search_entry in entries:
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/wiki/" + request.GET.get("q"))
        
        else: 
            for entry in entries: 
                if search_entry in entry: 
                    results.append(entry)
                    return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", {
                        "results": results,
                        "random": rand
                    })
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("create", views.create, name="create"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("edit/<str:title>", views.edit, name="edit"),
    path("<str:title>", views.entry, name="entry")
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>", views.mdpage, name="entry"),
    path("createpage",views.create, name="create"),
    path("wiki/edit/<str:title>", views.edit, name="edit"),
]
```